# Assign values from List to Object fields

Tags: apex, class

I need to assign values from a List to Object fields (User). I am getting an error  "Loop variable must be of type String". I will appreciate any help!

Class code:

```
  public class dashboardUserChartLines{

      public List<String> List1 {get;set;}
      public  Integer Stat_var;

   public dashboardUserChartLines(){

   //for mws chart
   AggregateResult[] groupedSales 
  =[SELECT CALENDAR_MONTH(Purchase_Date__c),CALENDAR_YEAR(Purchase_Date__c), SUM(Detail_Total__c)
   FROM MWSOrderItem__c 
   WHERE  Purchase_Date__c = LAST_N_DAYS:365 AND Buyer_lookup__c =:UserInfo.getUserId()
   GROUP BY CALENDAR_MONTH(Purchase_Date__c),CALENDAR_YEAR(Purchase_Date__c)
   ORDER BY CALENDAR_YEAR(Purchase_Date__c),CALENDAR_MONTH(Purchase_Date__c) ASC LIMIT 50000 ];

   List1 = new List<String>();  

   for (AggregateResult ar11 : groupedSales )  {

   List1.add(String.valueof(ar11.get('expr0')+'/'+String.valueof(ar11.get('expr1'))));
   List1.add(String.valueof(ar11.get('expr2')));

 }  

 if(List.Size()==24)

   for(User p : List1 ) { //here is the problem

    p.MWS_MonthYear1__c = String.valueof(List1.get(0)); 
    p.MWS_MonthYear2__c = String.valueof(List1.get(2)); 
    p.MWS_MonthYear3__c = String.valueof(List1.get(4)); 
    p.MWS_MonthYear4__c = String.valueof(List1.get(6)); 
    p.MWS_MonthYear5__c = String.valueof(List1.get(8)); 
    p.MWS_MonthYear6__c = String.valueof(List1.get(10)); 
    p.MWS_MonthYear7__c = String.valueof(List1.get(12)); 
    p.MWS_MonthYear8__c = String.valueof(List1.get(14)); 
    p.MWS_MonthYear9__c = String.valueof(List1.get(16)); 
    p.MWS_MonthYear10__c = String.valueof(List1.get(18)); 
    p.MWS_MonthYear11__c = String.valueof(List1.get(20)); 
    p.MWS_MonthYear12__c  = String.valueof(List1.get(22)); 

    p.MWS_Month1__c = Decimal.valueof(List1.get(1)); 
    p.MWS_Month2__c = Decimal.valueof(List1.get(3));   
    p.MWS_Month3__c = Decimal.valueof(List1.get(5));
    p.MWS_Month4__c = Decimal.valueof(List1.get(7));   
    p.MWS_Month5__c = Decimal.valueof(List1.get(9)); 
    p.MWS_Month6__c = Decimal.valueof(List1.get(11));   
    p.MWS_Month7__c = Decimal.valueof(List1.get(13)); 
    p.MWS_Month8__c = Decimal.valueof(List1.get(15));   
    p.MWS_Month9__c = Decimal.valueof(List1.get(17)); 
    p.MWS_Month10__c = Decimal.valueof(List1.get(19));   
    p.MWS_Month11__c = Decimal.valueof(List1.get(21)); 
    p.MWS_Month12__c = Decimal.valueof(List1.get(23));       
    }              
  }
 }   

}
```

Comment: Your list variable is of type **String** `List1 = new List<String>();` and your for loop is sObject **User** - `for(User p : List1 )`. Not sure what's happening in the rest of your code, but I guess you have another list of Users that you need to loop through?

Comment: Bachovski,That's all the code for the class

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You want to create new users, update the current user...?

Comment: I am calling this class using a trigger in the User Object.trigger dashboardUser on USER (before update) {

 if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
  new dashboardUserChartLines();
 }
} I would like to update the user fields when the trigger in the User Object is fired

Comment: For example if the object NRProducts is updated and the owner of the record is Carlos, It will fire the trigger in NRProducts, which will fire the trigger in User Object and update the fields, that was working just fine. But now I was requested to create a class that handles this. and I am lost

Comment: could you please help me

Answer (score 1):

Don't over list1, you just want to assign them to the user. You might want to try out some basic tutorials for javascript or any language you prefer. Loops and other constructs are pretty useful, and understanding them better will make you're life a lot easier if you're coding.

Class code:

```
  public class dashboardUserChartLines{

      public List<String> List1 {get;set;}
      public  Integer Stat_var;

   public dashboardUserChartLines(){

   //for mws chart
   AggregateResult[] groupedSales 
  =[SELECT CALENDAR_MONTH(Purchase_Date__c),CALENDAR_YEAR(Purchase_Date__c), SUM(Detail_Total__c)
   FROM MWSOrderItem__c 
   WHERE  Purchase_Date__c = LAST_N_DAYS:365 AND Buyer_lookup__c =:UserInfo.getUserId()
   GROUP BY CALENDAR_MONTH(Purchase_Date__c),CALENDAR_YEAR(Purchase_Date__c)
   ORDER BY CALENDAR_YEAR(Purchase_Date__c),CALENDAR_MONTH(Purchase_Date__c) ASC LIMIT 50000 ];

   List1 = new List<String>();  

   for (AggregateResult ar11 : groupedSales )  {

   List1.add(String.valueof(ar11.get('expr0')+'/'+String.valueof(ar11.get('expr1'))));
   List1.add(String.valueof(ar11.get('expr2')));

 }  

 if(List.Size()==24)

   User p = new User();

    p.MWS_MonthYear1__c = String.valueof(List1.get(0)); 
    p.MWS_MonthYear2__c = String.valueof(List1.get(2)); 
    p.MWS_MonthYear3__c = String.valueof(List1.get(4)); 
    p.MWS_MonthYear4__c = String.valueof(List1.get(6)); 
    p.MWS_MonthYear5__c = String.valueof(List1.get(8)); 
    p.MWS_MonthYear6__c = String.valueof(List1.get(10)); 
    p.MWS_MonthYear7__c = String.valueof(List1.get(12)); 
    p.MWS_MonthYear8__c = String.valueof(List1.get(14)); 
    p.MWS_MonthYear9__c = String.valueof(List1.get(16)); 
    p.MWS_MonthYear10__c = String.valueof(List1.get(18)); 
    p.MWS_MonthYear11__c = String.valueof(List1.get(20)); 
    p.MWS_MonthYear12__c  = String.valueof(List1.get(22)); 

    p.MWS_Month1__c = Decimal.valueof(List1.get(1)); 
    p.MWS_Month2__c = Decimal.valueof(List1.get(3));   
    p.MWS_Month3__c = Decimal.valueof(List1.get(5));
    p.MWS_Month4__c = Decimal.valueof(List1.get(7));   
    p.MWS_Month5__c = Decimal.valueof(List1.get(9)); 
    p.MWS_Month6__c = Decimal.valueof(List1.get(11));   
    p.MWS_Month7__c = Decimal.valueof(List1.get(13)); 
    p.MWS_Month8__c = Decimal.valueof(List1.get(15));   
    p.MWS_Month9__c = Decimal.valueof(List1.get(17)); 
    p.MWS_Month10__c = Decimal.valueof(List1.get(19));   
    p.MWS_Month11__c = Decimal.valueof(List1.get(21)); 
    p.MWS_Month12__c = Decimal.valueof(List1.get(23));       

  }
 }   

}
```